# Gnome/Metacity: Prevent windows from stealing focus when another window is closed

Tags: gnome, window-manager, metacity

Normally when I open applications A, B, C (in that order), if I then close C, focus shifts to B.  This is the default behavior and this is desirable to me.

However, it seems that Slack breaks this paradigm -- if Slack was A in the example above, it steals focus after C is closed.

Is there a method of fixing this in the Metacity config, or alternatively switching to another window manager that overrides focus-stealing from obstructive apps?  I plan to contact Slack about this, but obviously a solution in the wm is better.

Comment: This may be related: https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/971388836340170753